# Passing object from parent component to child component on submit

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to fetch values from a parent component and pass it to the child component on submit, and then display it in the child component. However, the object is not getting passed from inside the onSubmit function. Hence the child does not show any newly inserted values.

Parent ts file:

```
@Output() StudentAdded= new EventEmitter<Stud>();

onSubmit(){
   const firstname=this.fname.value;
   const lastname=this.lname.value;
   const date=this.dob.value;
   const newStud = new Stud(firstname,lastname,date);
   this.StudentAdded.emit(newStud);
}
```

Parent html:

```
<div class="col-xs 5">
    <app-stud-details [student]="newStudent"  (StudentAdded)="studAdded($event)"></app-stud-details>
</div>
```

In child:

```
export class StudDetailsComponent implements OnInit { 
  @Input() student: Stud;
  students: Stud[]=[new Stud('Test','Test','05-11-1922')];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  studAdded(student: Stud){
    this.students.push(student);
  }
}
```

Child html:

```
 <div class="col-xs-4" *ngFor="let student of students">
    {{'Name:'}}{{student.firstname}}{{' '+ student.lastname}}<br>
    {{'Date of Birth:'}}{{student.dob}}
  </div>
```

Comment: The output decorator goes up, not down. This means you're sending an event to the grandparent there.

Comment: @Maryannah Oh ok, so how do I send it the other way?

Comment: provide the output in the child !

Comment: Also move the `studAdded` method to the parent

Comment: @Maryannah If I provide Output in the child, then I would be sending data from the child to the parent right?

Comment: Yes, exactly ! To send from the parent to the child, it's the input decorator.

Comment: @Maryannah So I've removed the emitter from parent. Inside onsubmit, It now has just the input decorator: `  @Input() newStudent: Stud;` I've used `this.newStudent = newStud`. `studAdded` function has been moved to parent. I now get error `Can't bind to 'student' since it isn't a known property of 'app-stud-details'.`

Comment: This means the child should have an @Input property

Comment: @Maryannah So both the parent and child needs Input decorators now??? Man this is so confusing to me :(

Comment: No, only the child needs an input decorator ! Every decorator goes into the child, they just differ in their use. [The documentation for input](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-input-binding) and [the document for output](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event) might help you !

Comment: @Maryannah Ohk. Could you please take a look at my current code? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vi1nzm

Comment: [Here you go](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ebmlto?file=src/index.html)

Comment: @Maryannah What changes (if any) did you make? It still seems like the object is not getting pushed into the array.

Comment: None, I just made it work because you changed class names and component selectors. I didn't touch your own code.

Comment: @Maryannah Ohk :) I'll keep digging to see how I can fix it!

Answer (score 0):

As you have are passing `newStudent` as `@Input()` to child, detect its change and pass the new student on change to the students array

Parent.ts

```
onSubmit(){
   const firstname=this.fname.value;
   const lastname=this.lname.value;
   const date=this.dob.value;
   const newStud = new Stud(firstname,lastname,date);
   this.newStudent = newStud 
}
```

Child.ts:

```
 ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    const studChange = changes.student;

    if (studChange != undefined && studChange .previousValue != studChange .currentValue) {
      this.students.push(studChange.currentValue)
    }
  }
```

Please note that `@Output()` is defined in the child component to pass event to the parent